Typescript Export Not Exporting
Typescript's export isn't actually exporting anything.
"Exporting" (if that's what you want to call it) in the public_api.ts file from another library doesn't actually export from the other library.  It acts more like a "using" statement, where the other library has to be installed separately, in order to operate properly.
Scenario:
Library A contains several types, classes, and interfaces.
Library B uses Library A.
Library B exports Library A's types, etc. in its public_api.ts.
Expectation:
Devs should be able to install just Library B, and have access to Library A's types because they were "exported", right?
Actuality:
Not the case.  A dev is having to install both Library A and Library B in order for it to work.
This is a route rife with issues, and shouldn't be the case.
Does this mean that I need to copy-and-paste Library A's types into Library B, in order to be "exported" correctly?
Is reusability not a concept in Typescript?

I don't use typescript, but why would B export A's types? Shouldn't it rather depend on A, and then anybody that wants to use B needs to also pull in A, if the package manager doesn't resolve such transitive dependencies?

"Devs should be able to install just Library B"... install how, exactly? Any package manager supporting package.json dependencies (or peerDepencencies) should be able to do just that

If there was a build step in which exports from A would be bundled into B, then you're right, it will suffice with the built version of B to export all of A functions and interfaces, otherwise, you'll need the two libraries to do that.

@Phil, install using npm install.  The peer dependency (Library A, in this case) might be private, and unreachable by devs installing Library B.

@ffflabs, I was thinking about this approach, but after the bundling, the public_api.ts/index.ts file would have to be updated, and recompiled, as part of the build process, correct?  Otherwise, from my understanding, Library A's types wouldn't be available.

@user25611283 to keep changes in librart A up to date un the bundle, you would have to recompile from then on, right
